# How to have the website continue updating underneath an alert/popup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a simple rock, paper, scissors (with added elements) game using JS and .innerhtml, as well as brute forcing a bunch of stuff using if/else loops. The game takes place in series of alerts, and the JS is set to update .innerhtml upon a specific action, but this only happens when the alert is closed out of.

How do I get the innerhtml to update underneath the alert? I'd assume something would have to be added near document.getElementById or .src but I have no idea and google hasn't helped.

```
       if (choice2 === "lizard") {
        document.getElementById("images2").getElementsByTagName("img")[0].src = "http://i.picresize.com/images/2015/03/04/G3cY.jpg";
    }
```

The website can be found [here](https://som.neocities.org)

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLztbwf/) a link to the JSFiddle, although that's just the javascript

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Alerts are a blocking function and nothing else can happen while one is up. This is why browsers generally ask you if you want to stop alerts after 2 or 3 of them come  up.

The alternative is to use a div modal that pops up instead.